# Paypal error "Transaction declined"

Tags: php, paypal, payflowlink

I'm using the legacy Payflow Link to process payments in a PHP application. It bounces users to Paypal to accept payments. At the end of the transaction, Paypal "posts" result data to a URL provided by me. The postback URL is this-

> https://registrations.isr.umich.edu/siapp/paypalcallback

My URL is valid, however, paypal is having trouble posting data to my "POST" HTTP method.

This is the message I'm getting from paypal:

> Your transaction was approved! However, a communication error with the merchant's site occured.
>
> The transaction has been voided, please contact the merchant.

This usually happens when paypal doesn't receive HTTP response code 200-OK from the given postback URL, it attempts to reach. I've tested my postback URL using an external REST client and it appears to be fine.

Also, this code works fine on a different server.

What is going on? Further more, I'd love to find out how I can capture a detailed error message from Paypal vs the generic message.

Comment: Can you paste the return of paypal?

Comment: it doesn't make it to my "post URL", so I don't know how to get the return of paypal. I only see this generic message on my webpage

Comment: You need to make sure that your account is set to live for live transactions? Have you tried with sandbox account? does it work?

Comment: My account is set for live transactions.